# For each row in a database sheet, create a copy of a template sheet, add values and save as pdf

Tags: google-apps-script

Im working on App Script for the first time and am stuck with code.

what i require is: there is a product database file and a product details template. For each product (row) in the product database file, i want to create a individual product details file (of each row from database) and save it as pdf in a different folder. the product details should be saved in a template sheet format by creating a copy of it.

but im not able to set the values in the new created copy of the template sheet.

would grateful appreciate any assistance.

the code so far is

```
function AutofillDocFromTemplate(){
   
   
   var templateID = SpreadsheetApp.openById("19MSLlFflVCuvz2_c_i3l2sIpvWRNH5UCmfJe5srtDgA");
   var templateSheet = templateID.getSheetByName("Template");
   var URLsheet = templateID.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
   var FOLDER_NAME = "pdfs";
  
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  for (var i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var tempID = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID.getId()).makeCopy();
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(tempID.getId()).setName("Product Details" + row[1]);
    
       
        
    templateSheet.getRange(10, 2, 1, 2).setValue(row[0]);
    templateSheet.getRange(10, 3, 1, 3).setValue(row[1]);
    templateSheet.getRange(7, 3, 1, 4).setValue(row[2]);
    templateSheet.getRange(12, 2, 5, 3).setValue(row[4]);
    templateSheet.getRange(17, 3).setValue(row[5]);
    templateSheet.getRange(13, 6).setValue(row[29]);
    templateSheet.getRange(14, 6).setValue(row[30]);
    templateSheet.getRange(15, 6).setValue(row[31]);
    templateSheet.getRange(16, 6).setValue(row[32]);
   
    var newfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("19cPRitCBguf_9pa1AXQLCp4PZzWQ0b3z");
    var oldfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("18w9HWOHwRz_vUX5EsJlAxc-6yM7UsowY");
    newfolder.addFile(file);
    oldfolder.removeFile(file);
    
    var pdffolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("19cPRitCBguf_9pa1AXQLCp4PZzWQ0b3z");
    var pdfFILE = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
    pdfFILE.setName(file.getName() + ".pdf");
    var theFolder = pdffolder;
    var theFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfFILE);
    theFolder.addFile(theFile);
     

        var pdfEMAIL = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
        var message = "Hi!,\nPlease find product deatils attached.\nMany Thanks!\nMe";
        //var emailAdd = sheet.getRange("D2").getValue()
        var emailTo = "xxx@gmail.com"; // add customer email here
        var subject = "Product Details " + row[2]; 
        
        var attach = {fileName:"Product Details" + file.getName() + '.pdf',content:pdfEMAIL, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});
        //file.setTrashed(true);
       
      //var rangesAddressesList = ['C7', 'D7', 'E7', 'F7', 'B10', 'C10', 'D10', 'E10', 'F10', 'B12', 'C12', 'D12', 'B13', 'C13', 'D13', 'B14', 'C14', 'D14', 'B15', 'C15', 'D15', 'B16', 'C16', 'D16', 'F13', 'F14', 'F15', 'F16', 'C17'];
      //templateSheet.getRangeList(rangesAddressesList).clearContent();
     
             
   }  
     ss.toast("Email Sent and PDF saved")
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for (var i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var tempID = DriveApp.getFileById(templateID.getId()).makeCopy();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(tempID.getId()).setName("Product Details" + row[1]);
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
  const sh=ss.getSheets()[0];//Get the first sheet in the spreadsheet.  You could also use getSheetByName() if you wish
  sh.getRange(10, 2, 1, 2).setValue(row[0]);
  sh.getRange(10, 3, 1, 3).setValue(row[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. worked like a charm. just have one issue now
the pdf that are getting created are empty.